# Icecat: chat-login brigs to global-fallback

Tags: support, chat, login

I am using [GNU IceCat](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnuzilla/) 31.2.0 on [Trisquel GNU/Linux](https://trisquel.info).

When I tries to login into chat, https://stackexchange.com/users/chat-login brigs me to https://chat.stackexchange.com/login/global-fallback.

I've tried following things but no success:-

- Disabled HTTPS Everywhere
- Cleared all history, cache etc:

  [image: screenshot]
- Allowed pop-ups for `[*.]stackexchange.com` & `stackauth.com`:

  [image: screenshot2]

***(Please tell me if there are other settings (like by using `about:config`) for cookies or data exceptions.***

**Let me tell you that currently I've not enabled any extra privacy features (All Unchecked):**

[image: privacy-features]

**Status from https://chat.stackexchange.com/help**:-

[image: screenshot3]

---

I've also visited similar questions but still no success. (Before closing as duplicate, give/link me answer containing solution that work for me!)

How can I fix this issue?

---

Note that I am surprised when found [meta chat login](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com) working fine instead of [normal](https://chat.stackexchange.com)!!

Comment: I fear there's no solution - SE can't possibly support all browsers. Use a common browser.

Comment: OK. I found one [`epiphany-browser`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_(web_browser)) : [(Intuitive GNOME web browse)](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Web/) available on [Trisquel's repository](http://packages.trisquel.info/belenos/epiphany-browser) which is working excellent and I can successfully login to [chat](http://stackexchange.com/users/chat-login) through it!

Comment: Well, don't be surprised if other things suddenly break...

Comment: @ShadowWizard I've not found any break yet. (What type of sudden break you are warning about?)

Comment: Good for you... dunno what might break, just a friendly warning so that you won't be surprised - it might be as minor as some pixels mismatch, or as major as failed login. No idea why you're so against common browsers, but that's not my place to judge.

Comment: OK, BTW I am not against common browsers, I am with [free](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html) [software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software). (probably against with [proprietary](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/proprietary.html) [software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proprietary_software))

Comment: Same problem with Debian’s Iceweasel.

Comment: @unor Which OS?

Comment: @Pandyan: Debian ;-) It’s [Debian’s version of Mozilla Firefox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Corporation_software_rebranded_by_the_Debian_project#IceWeasel) without the trademarked parts (same idea like GNU IceCat, but a different project).

Comment: +1 here - Iceweasel on current Debian Testing. I'll be direct: Do these meta questions reach people who are working for SE and in a position to provide some technical insight into the problem - this might after all be something that can and has to be fixed browser-side - or is this like many support forums that have been outsourced to the user community, where things like "have you restarted the application/your computer" are the most common answer and thread-ender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today when I tried to login chat-room, I found this issue fixed.

Now I can successfully use chat-rooms of chat.SE as well as chat.meta.SE on GNU ICeCat.

<sup>So, I am superseded and while [chatting](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3686924#3686924) found what is going on:</sup>

Visit [**Upcoming login changes (Stage 2 now LIVE)**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260153/260388) for further information.

Quoted Information:

> **What this means *right now*:**

> 1. When you log into any Q&A site on the stackexchange.com domain, you will be automatically logged into all other Q&A sites on the stackexchange.com domain + stackexchange.com itself.
>    - Area 51 is excluded from this.

> 2. stackoverflow.com, superuser.com, and other Q&A sites with their own domains will still use the old flow.

> 3. We are going to recognize you *in some ways* on sites where you don't have a profile. This is still a work in progress, but most notably you will see "join this community" in the top bar instead of "sign up" and "log in".